# Laravel 5.8 multiple auth registration and login

Tags: php, laravel

I have created Student table for registering students and make them login directly after registration... but it seems that data are inserted in the table, but they can't get redirected to their page, and cannot even log in

I have tried using student guards and making function to the register controller that will redirect them after registering, but nothing works.... Am still new in laravel

/* My register codes*/

```
/* my register controller */
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

    use App\User;
    use App\Student;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    class RegisterController extends Controller
    {
        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Register Controller
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
        | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
        | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
        |
        */

        use RegistersUsers;

        /**
         * Where to redirect users after registration.
         *
         * @var string
         */
        protected $redirectTo = '/home';

        /**
         * Create a new controller instance.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        // public function __construct()
        // {
        //     $this->middleware('guest');
        // }

          public function __construct()
        {
            $this->middleware('guest');
            $this->middleware('guest:student');
        }

        /**
         * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
         *
         * @param  array  $data
         * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
         */
        protected function validator(array $data)
        {
            return Validator::make($data, [
                'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
                'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
                'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
            ]);
        }

        /**
         * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
         *
         * @param  array  $data
         * @return \App\User
         */
        protected function create(array $data)
        {
            return User::create([
                'name' => $data['name'],
                'email' => $data['email'],
                'role_id' => $data['role_id'],
                'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            ]);
        }

        public function showStudentRegisterForm()
        {
            return view('auth.register', ['url' => 'student']);
        }

         protected function createStudent(Request $request)
        {
            // dd($request);
            // $this->validator($request->all())->validate();
            $student = Student::create([
                'fname' => $request['fname'],
                'lname' => $request['lname'],
                'email' => $request['email'],
                'role_id' => $request['role_id'],
                'password' => Hash::make($request['password']),
            ]);
            return redirect()->intended('/home');
        }
    }


    /* My Login controller */

    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

    class LoginController extends Controller
    {
        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Login Controller
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
        | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
        | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
        |
        */

        use AuthenticatesUsers;

        /**
         * Where to redirect users after login.
         *
         * @var string
         */
        protected $redirectTo = '/home';

        /**
         * Create a new controller instance.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
            $this->middleware('guest:student')->except('logout');
        }

         public function showStudentLoginForm()
        {
            return view('auth.login', ['url' => 'student']);
        }

        public function studentLogin(Request $request)
        {
            $this->validate($request, [
                'email'   => 'required|email',
                'password' => 'required|min:6'
            ]);

            if (Auth::guard('student')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->get('remember'))) {

                return redirect()->intended('/home');
            }
            return back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));
        }
    }



    /* redirect if authenticated */

    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Middleware;

    use Closure;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

    class RedirectIfAuthenticated
    {
        /**
         * Handle an incoming request.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @param  \Closure  $next
         * @param  string|null  $guard
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
        {
            if ($guard == "student" && Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                    return redirect('/home');
                }


            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                return redirect('/home');
            }


            return $next($request);
        }


    }


    /* my routes */


    Route::get('/login/student', 'Auth\LoginController@showStudentLoginForm');
    Route::get('/register/student', 'Auth\RegisterController@showStudentRegisterForm');
    Route::post('/login/student', 'Auth\LoginController@StudentLogin');
    Route::post('/register/student', 'Auth\RegisterController@createStudent');


    /* my guards */


    <?php

    return [

        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Authentication Defaults
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
        | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
        | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
        |
        */

        'defaults' => [
            'guard' => 'web',
            'passwords' => 'users',
        ],

        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Authentication Guards
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
        | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
        | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
        |
        | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
        | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
        | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
        |
        | Supported: "session", "token"
        |
        */

        'guards' => [
            'web' => [
                'driver' => 'session',
                'provider' => 'users',
            ],

            'api' => [
                'driver' => 'token',
                'provider' => 'users',
                'hash' => false,
            ],

            'student' => [
                'driver' => 'session',
                'provider' => 'students',
            ],
        ],

        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | User Providers
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
        | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
        | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
        |
        | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
        | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
        | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
        |
        | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
        |
        */

        'providers' => [
            'users' => [
                'driver' => 'eloquent',
                'model' => App\User::class,
            ],

            'students' => [
                'driver' => 'eloquent',
                'model' => App\Student::class,
            ],

            // 'users' => [
            //     'driver' => 'database',
            //     'table' => 'users',
            // ],
        ],

        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Resetting Passwords
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
        | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
        | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
        |
        | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
        | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
        | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
        |
        */

        'passwords' => [
            'users' => [
                'provider' => 'users',
                'table' => 'password_resets',
                'expire' => 60,
            ],
        ],

    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should login the student after registering, this what your code should look like

```
protected function createStudent(Request $request)
    {

        $student = Student::create([
            'fname' => $request['fname'],
            'lname' => $request['lname'],
            'email' => $request['email'],
            'role_id' => $request['role_id'],
            'password' => Hash::make($request['password']),
        ]);

      //After registration login the use then redirect
       if (Auth::guard('student')
                 ->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])) {

            return redirect()->intended('/home');
        }

    }
```

Comment: I tried it, it gives me this error (This page isn’t working localhost redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS)  I even tried to use  "if ($guard == "student" && Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                return redirect('/home');
            }" in RedirectAuthenticated.php but it didnt work

Comment: I think the problem is with the ```guard```

Comment: If you would show me those problems in above guards i posted, it'll be very appreciated bro... am really strugling